# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: users.login

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlite database and I declare the model as this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    # Required for administrative interface
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

And I have add a Model instance like this:

```
admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example: Auth', index_view=MyAdminIndexView(), base_template='my_master.html')

admin.add_view(MyModelView(User, db.session))

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

if db.session.query(User).filter_by(login='passport').count() <= 1:
    user = User(login = 'passport', password = 'password')
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

However, if I comment the db.drop_all(), it will occur an error which is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: users.login [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('passport', 'password')]
```

And if do not comment the db.drop_all(), everything is fun. Because there are other tables on this database, I do not want to drop all the tables when I run it. Are there any other solutions to fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing the count to `<= 1`.
So you'll attempt to create the new user even though it already exists.
So it should probably simply be `< 1`:

```
if db.session.query(User).filter_by(login='passport').count() < 1:
    user = User(login = 'passport', password = 'password')
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just run query, let's say:

```
db.session.query(User).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

OR

```
User.query.delete()
db.session.commit()
```

in that case, you will just remove everything from User table.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error.

```
if db.session.query(User).filter_by(login='passport').count() <= 1:
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
user = User(login = 'passport', password = 'password')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31902255)